# RAID controller link speed with mixed drive types

Tags: storage, hardware-raid, sas, sata

What will be the negotiated speed if I mix 6 and 12gbps SATA and SAS drives in a single h/w RAID controller, but keep them in the separate raid groups? Let's take LSI (Dell PERC H730) as an example with 2 x SATA @6Gbps in RAID1 and 2 x SAS @12Gbps in RAID1 in another. Will the SAS disks negotiate to their max of 12 or step down to 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link speed negotiation is done on a per-port basis, so it should be possible to have SATA 3.0 (6 Gb/s) and SAS 3.0 (12 Gb/s) connected to the same PERC card at maximum speed.

However, you can not (and should not) mix them in the same virtual disk / array. In other words, keep them in separate array and all should works without issues.

From [PERC H730 manual](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/poweredge-rc-h330_users-guide_en-us.pdf):

> Combining SAS and SATA hard drives within a virtual disk is not
> supported. Also, combining hard drives and solid state drives (SSDs)
> within a virtual disk is not supported

No similar statements is done for mixing SATA 3.0 and 6.0 Gpbs drives, and `omreport storage pdisk controller=0` reports link speed on a per-drive basis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you happen to have any reference to a documentation to support this?

Comment: @LubosA.I've updated my answer